# Hour of Python Trinket Number of Things challenge

Tags: python, if-statement

I was doing the "Number of Things" challenge on the Hour of Python Trinket website (https://hourofpython.trinket.io/python-challenges#/string-challenges/number-of-things-challenge) and was able to follow a tutorial on The Clever Programmer youtube channel to help.

The challenge creates a sentence which pluralizes depending on the [0] int in the list. In the [1] slot, the string "trinket" would be returned as "trinkets" adding an 's' at the end.

To take it a step further, I wanted to add a line that would see a word that ends in 's' (in my example 'boss') and add 'es' instead of 's'. I tried using an *elif* statement after the first *if* statement but it keeps appending "s". I would like the first statement to say "There are 5 bosses"

I'm a novice learning Python now. Please be gentle haha.

```
# Make a function how_many that, given a list of a number
# and a thing name, returns a grmmatically correct sentence
# describing the number of things.
#
# >>> how_many([5, "trinket"])
# There are 5 trinkets.
# >>>> how_many([1, "king"])
# There is 1 king.


def how_many(the_list):
  # Add code here that returns the answer
  dg = str(the_list[1])
  if the_list[0] > 1:
    return "There are " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1] + 's'
  elif dg[-1] == "s":
    return "There are " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1] + 'es'
  else:
    return "There is " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1]

# Add print statements here to test what your code does:"""
print how_many([5, "boss"])
print how_many([1, "king"])

______
```

Prints:
There are 5 bosss
There is 1 king

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make your if statements more explicit.  Right now, you check if `the_list[0] >`, but then have an `elif` to check if the word ends in `'s'`, so this will never be reached when you want it to.

I would recommend using Python's ternary operator to check which condition to use, and then appending what is necessary.

```
def how_many(the_list):
  dg = str(the_list[1])
  if the_list[0] > 1:
    return "There are " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1] + \
           ('s' if dg[-1] != 's' else 'es')
  else:
    return "There is " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1]

print(how_many([5, "boss"]))
print(how_many([1, "king"]))
```

Output:

```
    There are 5 bosses
    There is 1 king
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight on ternary statements! Seems very convenient for situations like this. I see you wrapped it in a parenthesis. Does this allow the return statement to read the ternary statement as a grouped item or are all ternary statements written in parenthesis?

Comment: If you don't have the statement in parenthesis, it will just return the result of the `else` instead of evaluating the else and appending it to the string.

Comment: @EricCastillo glad to help.  If any of the answers here answered your question.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid checking `the_list[0] > 1` again if `dg[-1] != "s"`:

```
def how_many(the_list):
  # Add code here that returns the answer
  dg = str(the_list[1])
  if the_list[0] > 1:
      if dg[-1] == "s":
          return "There are " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1] + 'es' 
      else:
          return "There are " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1] + 's'
  else:
      return "There is " + str(the_list[0]) + ' ' + the_list[1]

# Add print statements here to test what your code does:"""
print(how_many([5, "boss"]))
print(how_many([1, "king"]))
# There are 5 bosses
# There is 1 king
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realize now you can put an if-else within an if, which avoids checking the_list[0] > 1 twice. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you. :)